# multicast socket doesn't work after the machine wakes up from sleep or hibernate in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, multicastsocket

This question is similar with [multicast socket - will not work when computer wakes up from sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944486/multicast-socket-will-not-work-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep). But that question was already closed and its solution is not what I want.

I have a code about multicast socket receive. It can work in Windows XP, 7 and Mac. But now I found a issue, "when I run it in windows 7, hibernate or sleep the PC, and then wake up the PC, the socket can't receive any more". It happens just in Windows 7. No problem in XP and MAC."

The code is like this:

```
final InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("234.255.255.255");
final MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(5555);

socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.setTimeToLive(10);
socket.joinGroup(group);

final int length = 4 * 1024;
final byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, length);

while(true) 
{
    socket.receive(packet);
    ...
}
...
```

Anyone has any idea about it?

I already tried many ways to explore it. I ever used WireShark to monitor the network adapter and I can see the multicast packets received to the PC. However, the java socket can't receive all the way.